# SOQL For Loop Architecture Question

Tags: soql, loop, collection

I have a pretty simple/general question, out of the two approaches below, what is the best method when querying and looping over a collection?

Approach 1:

```
for(Account a : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]){
     //do some stuff
}
```

Approach 2:

```
List<Account> acctList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];

for(Account a : acctList){
       //do some stuff
}
```

I recently ran into a limitation with subqueries using approach 1 that didn't apply with approach 2, I'm wondering if there are any other pros/cons to using one as opposed to the other?

Comment: I don't think , there is much difference in these two apart from saving a variable in the first approach. You can use the sub queries in the first approach as well .  for (account A : [select id ,(select id from contacts) from account]{ }... You can access the related contacts with A.contacts...

Comment: Yeah, I was doing that but received an "Aggregate Query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop" when I subqueried using Approach 1. I didn't receive that error when I used Approach 2. (there were more than 500 child records in the subquery for one parent)

Comment: are you using an aggregate function in the sub query ?

Comment: No, just a nested/subquery.

Comment: These guys were having the same issue: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093HqIAI

Comment: You should probably ask a separate question about that particular error then and include its text as well as code for context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a significant heap benefit by using the former. It induces batching (see [SOQL For Loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm)) so it doesn't have to load the whole list into memory at once. Money quote (emphasis mine):

> SOQL for loops differ from standard SOQL statements because of the method they use to retrieve sObjects. While the standard queries discussed in [SOQL and SOSL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL.htm) can retrieve either the count of a query or a number of object records, SOQL for loops retrieve all sObjects, using efficient chunking with calls to the query and queryMore methods of the SOAP API. **Developers should always use a SOQL for loop to process query results that return many records, to avoid the limit on [heap size](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#total_heap_size_limit_desc)**.

Comment: Also, you can break the loop early without burning through your entire query limit (50,000 rows per transaction). I recently discovered this myself. It's pretty cool. For example: `Integer counter = 0;
for(Account record:[SELECT Id FROM Account]) {
    counter++;
    if(counter==5000) {
        break;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think , there is much difference in these two apart from saving a variable in the first approach. You can use the sub queries in the first approach as well . for example

```
for (account A : [select id ,(select id from contacts) from account]){ 
         system.debug('--' + A.contacts);
}
```

... You can access the related contacts with A.contacts..